# Read kafka messages using Python Airflow

Tags: python, apache-kafka, airflow

I am new to Kafka integration with Python and Airflow. I am trying to read a kafka topic using a Airflow DAG. However, the messages seems to be in binary format when I print it. What do I need to do to convert this into the original text?

Here is the code I have so far:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKIwG.png)

I was expecting to see the original content in a human readable string format but the above code is giving binary format as follow.

message key: b'\x00\x00\x00\x01xH83ecca24-4a65-4af2-b82a-ecb7a347a639' || message value: b'\x00\x00\x003\nH83ecca24-4a65-4af2-b82a-ecb7a347a639\x1cPR30112023RE06\xa6\xa0\x14\x02\x14Reno FSP 1\x02\xb0\x98\x11\x00\x06\x80\xc0\xe6\xaa\x84c\xdc\x93\x0c\x82\xd6\x94\x8b\x84c\x82\xd6\x94\x8b\x84c\xdc\x93\x0c\x00\x00\x02\x00\x02H86a68700-f0fb-41a9-ad96-37723eee2878\x80\xc8\x93\x8b\x84c\x0ccustom\x06125\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
[2023-12-13, 08:53:10 CST] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - Successfully poll a record from Kafka topic: test_topic, partition: 3, offset: 4

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not an image.

Comment: def consume_function(message, prefix=None):
    if message.value() is not None and message.key() is not None:
        print(f"Successfully poll a record from " +
          f"{message.value()}"

with DAG(dag_id="kafka_text_1",
         ) as dag:

    consume_message = ConsumeFromTopicOperator(
        task_id="consume_message",
        kafka_config_id="kafka_default",
        topics=["test_topic"],
        apply_function=consume_function,
        poll_timeout=20,
        max_messages=20,
        max_batch_size=20
    )
consume_message

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is really just a append only file of bytes underneath the hood. So you received an encoded message.

You can decode with `msg_key.decode()` and `msg.decode()`.

I am not sure what the exact library is being used, but you have to decode the message and key separately.